# Unable to center a navbar-list-item inside navbar-list

Tags: html, css

Here is how my header looks:

[image]

As you can see, the yellow box is not at the center of the red box. How can place it at the center?

My code snippets are as follows:

Header.js

```
import React from "react";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul className="navbar-list">
          <li className="navbar-list-item">Register/Login</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

index.css
The following is my complete `index.css` code. I don't have any other CSS file.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6rem;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 0.3rem solid green;
}

nav {
  margin-right: 3rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid red;
}

.navbar-list {
  list-style: none;
  border: 0.1rem solid gold;
}

.navbar-list-item {
  color: gainsboro;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

GIT REPOSITORY

https://github.com/sundaray/book

Comment: I think you have something else interfering - when i copy just the css and html (not using it in a react setting), the <li> is already vertically centered

Comment: Hmm, what could be wrong then?

Comment: I don't know without seeing the rest of the setup, but if you isolate the css and html it seems to be fine, so maybe you have other css interferring somewhere?

Comment: I don't have any other css except basic font settings inside `index.css`.

Comment: What browser are you using? I am on chrome and it's showing that the <nav> has a margin set as a browser default on <nav> tags, so it might be showing differently on another browser.
I would do the following... give your <nav> a specified height and set margin:0;
On the <ul> add the following to vertically centre....
margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
Try it and see

Comment: I am using Chrome. Also, see my complete `index.css` in the question.

Comment: I have added the GitHub repo link in the question. Can you please take a look?

Comment: ok, now the <ul>sits inside the <nav> with no spacing around it.
Give your nav a height of say 50px. 
Now add this to your .navbar-list..... margin: 0; position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translate(0, -50%);

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Pls. post your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your nav a height of say 50px.

Now add this to your `.navbar-list`:

`margin: 0; position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translate(0, -50%);`

This essentially offsets the elements top positioning, and then bumps it upward by 50% of its own height, making it vertically centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. Also, you have margin-bottom being set from bootstrap which needs to be overridden

```
nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to center the `navbar-list` inside `nav`, not center what is inside `navbar-list`.

Comment: you can do the same for nav in that case. edited my response

Comment: something else is interfering with your CSS. i created this sandbox with your code and it seems to be working fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-tree-m5kcm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: doesn't seem to be browser issue as well. check if something is overriding in dev console

Comment: I have added the link to the github repo in the question. Can you please take a look?

Comment: its working now. check out now. updated the answer with explanation